# Interpretation of a graph created by the R package seas

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R studio and R in general, I am not even sure if this is the right place to ask this question. I was instructed to draw a graph showing seasonality using daily rainfall over a number of years. I need help more in interpreting the graph than in plotting it. 
There is an example already in R using `mscdata` that I was able to replicate using my own data, the code for the example is as below. Any help with what this graph means or explains will be greatly appreciated.Thank you

```
install.packages(seas)
library(seas)
data(mscdata)
dat <- mksub(mscdata, id=1108447)
dat.ss <- seas.sum(dat, width="mon")
x<-mscdata
# Structure in R
str(dat.ss)
tail(mscdata)
# Annual data
dat.ss$ann

# Demonstrate how to slice through a cubic array
dat.ss$seas["1990",,]
dat.ss$seas[,2,] # or "Feb", if using English locale
dat.ss$seas[,,"precip"]

# Simple calculation on an array
(monthly.mean <- apply(dat.ss$seas[,,"precip"], 2, mean,na.rm=TRUE))
barplot(monthly.mean, ylab="Mean monthly total (mm/month)",
        main="Un-normalized mean precipitation in Vancouver, BC")
text(6.5, 150, paste("Un-normalized rates given 'per month' should be",
                     "avoided since ~3-9% error is introduced",
                     "to the analysis between months", sep="\n"))

# Normalized precip
norm.monthly <- dat.ss$seas[,,"precip"] / dat.ss$days
norm.monthly.mean <- apply(norm.monthly, 2, mean,na.rm=TRUE)
print(round(norm.monthly, 2))
print(round(norm.monthly.mean, 2))
barplot(norm.monthly.mean,
        ylab="Normalized mean monthly total (mm/day)",
        main="Normalized mean precipitation in Vancouver, BC")

# Better graphics of data
dat.ss <- seas.sum(dat, width=11)
image(dat.ss)
```

This code gives a graph showing sample quartiles, annual rainfall but I don't really know what it means. Any help whatsoever will be appreciated

The Graph using the package seas is as below 
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pmfI.png)

Comment: I think you should include your plot more than your code(not to say you should not include code) so as to get a visual idea of what you would like to interpret. Sounds more like a Stats question.

Comment: @NelsonGon I have edited to include the graph but i am not sure what you mean by it is a stats question, i just created an account on this site so i have no idea what i am doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start with the top left graph :

You've probably guessed that each row is a year (as shown by the Y-axis) while day groups/months of the year are X-axis. The color of each box of the heatmap is proportionally darker according to the mm's worth of rain in that day group, with the scale being displayed on the far right. I assume the red X's mean missing values.

Top right is like a barplot with the sum of rainfall each year (row), just continuously plotted. The red bar should be the average precipitation overall (not sure about the orange one).

Bottom left is a bit more tricky. Think of it like you reordered the rows in each column to have the heaviest rainfall of the day group at the top (forgetting about the year info here). The Y-axis shows the quantiles. The quantiles' respective values change for each day group, so the lines you see on top of the plot indicate key rainfall values in mm (4,6,8,10,12). Indeed, If you look at the 2mm line (lowest one), you'll see that in January, about 20% of rainfalls (across all years) are below this threshold, while in the end of July, over 80% are below  2mm (expect less rainfall in the summer).

Lastly, bottom right is similar to the one above it. It's the sum of all rows, referring to the quantiles rather than years this time, resulting in the staircase pattern. 
You'll notice that since the scale of the plot is the same as the one showing the average per year, the top of the staircase is outside of the plot...

Hope I made that clear enough.

Comment: Thank you so so much, you've made it pretty clear, Thank you.